# Finding an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^3$ so that matrix representation consists of blocks of a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd

**Problem:** Suppose $A$ from $\mathbb{C}^3$ to $\mathbb{C}^3$ is given by
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & -3 \\
-2 & 3 & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$

**Question:** How to find an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$ so that the matrix representation of $A$ consists of blocks of the form
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \lambda_i \\
\lambda_i & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
and otherwise all zeros?

**Attempt so far:** Suppose I try first to get a singular value decomposition $A$. Then $A^TA = V\Sigma^2 V^T$ and $AA^T = U\Sigma^2 U^T$.  Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, we have that $A^TA = AA^T$ so that $U = V$ consisting of an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $AA^T$.

Now $AA^T$ has a eigenvalue of $0$ and a repeated eigenvalue of $14$ with two eigenvectors.  I can use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthogonal basis from these eigenvectors and construct $V$.

But then I think I should be getting that $A = U\Sigma V^T = V\Sigma V^T$ but it's not working out that way.  Here's $V$ and my $\Sigma$:
$$
V=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{14}} & -\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}} & -\dfrac{9}{\sqrt{1638}}\\
\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{14}}& \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}} & -\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{1638}} \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}} & 0 & \dfrac{39}{\sqrt{1638}}
\end{array}\right].
$$
$$
\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{14} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{14}
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: your original matrix  $A$ is skew hermitian, so observe that $Q^*V^* AV Q$ is also skew hermitian for $V, Q\in U_n(\mathbb C)$.  As you did in a prior edit, first diagonalize $A$ with a unitary matrix *not a real orthogonal matrix* so $A=VD V^*$.  Then try using $Q:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: @user8675309 What does the asterisk stand for in $Q^{*}$, for example?

Comment: the $*$ denotes the *conjugate transpose* of a matrix.  You cannot stay within reals in this problem.  Your original matrix $A$ is skew symmetric (in reals) and you wrote $A=V\Sigma V^T$ for invertible $V$ which implies $\Sigma$ is skew symmetric but $\Sigma$ is diagonal hence symmetric, so $\Sigma$ is both symmetric and skew-symmetric, i.e $\Sigma =\mathbf 0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user8675309 Is it not the case that $U$ equals $V$ in the SVD since the way you solve for $U$ is by finding eigenvectors of $AA^T$ and the way you solve for $V$ is by finding eigenvectors of $A^TA$, but $AA^T = A^TA$ in this particular problem since $A$ is skew-symmetric?

Comment: That is false; my prior comment tells you it gives a contradiction.  Your procedural justification doesn't even work when $A$ is real symmetric indefinite.  As I said in my first comment, stop with the SVD and instead first diagonalize $A$ with a unitary matrix...